# Wifi stopped connecting to some networks after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, upgrade

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and my laptop stopped connecting to some Wi-fi networks it had connected to before, but continues to connect OK to other ones.

The not connecting network (`HH40V_2014` further in the info): it starts `connecting`, it asks for a password after a while, I provide the correct password, keeps `connecting`, it ends up asking again.

The connecting network (`CheckVienna free WiFi` further in the info): it connects OK as previously on 18.04.

My info from Wireless Info Script (based on https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/471632 ):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 May 2021 17:06 CEST +0200

Booted last: 25 May 2021 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-73-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 17:39:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 48)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 06cb:7680 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
Bus 002 Device 030: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:0221 Apple, Inc. Aluminum Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
iwlmvm                380928  0
mac80211              847872  1 iwlmvm
acer_wmi               24576  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               331776  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              704512  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,intel_vbtn
video                  49152  2 acer_wmi,i915
wmi                    32768  2 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet6 fe80::f11:ac07:b9e:4d60/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether <MAC 'docker0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.9/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 2925sec preferred_lft 2925sec
    inet6 fe80::e507:5b67:4045:7c5f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

docker0   no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.9 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1290       1  0 May24 ?        00:01:24 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Xiaomi Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Ethernet connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       214f6339-8377-4d3b-bd17-3b6fb19f4570
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/37
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1621958088
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = sloup
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.9
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e507:5b67:4045:7c5f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/112
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   214f6339-8377-4d3b-bd17-3b6fb19f4570 | Ethernet connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'docker0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       docker0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       f1225fe4-0a5b-4445-8272-326484a294aa
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.17.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/135
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f1225fe4-0a5b-4445-8272-326484a294aa | docker0

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.4.0-73-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               17.3216344376.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          70 (connecting (getting IP configuration))
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     CheckVienna free WiFi
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5e8dcbf2-f1dc-4126-b8f4-284c02717f21
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/40
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     6 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/56,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/72,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/114
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   3e1a6d31-fb6f-49c1-960d-aaa0b6661705 | Ubuntu
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   8299c059-44dd-47a9-b80f-bda6b69dc2af | HH40V_2014
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   5e8dcbf2-f1dc-4126-b8f4-284c02717f21 | CheckVienna free WiFi

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                   BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
HH40V_2014             <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  130 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no             
CheckVienna free WiFi  <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  270 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  --        no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[Deleted, containing personal info + too long for a question here]

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

docker0   no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
[Deleted, too long for a question here]

##### iwlist scan #######################

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)

wlp1s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HH40V_2014"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000378cd5baf6
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3104ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################
[Deleted, too long for a question here]

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf]
options hid_apple swap_fn_leftctrl=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[100834.452581] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[100834.560601] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[100834.664578] wlp1s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> timed out
[100839.526368] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>
[100839.530823] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100839.540729] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100839.544630] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100839.648613] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[100839.752616] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[100839.856608] wlp1s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> timed out
[100853.194659] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>
[100853.199025] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100853.209736] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100853.212701] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100853.316692] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[100853.420757] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[100853.528772] wlp1s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> timed out
[100864.515077] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>
[100864.519522] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100864.530287] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100864.532762] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100864.636749] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[100864.740763] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[100864.848756] wlp1s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> timed out
[100875.778394] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]>
[100875.782172] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100875.792066] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100875.792813] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[100875.896822] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[100876.000825] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[100876.104830] wlp1s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_2014' [AC1]> timed out
[100890.314229] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[100890.319535] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[100890.321320] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100890.324890] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[100890.326142] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=4)
[100890.327879] wlp1s0: associated
[100890.328830] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[100908.164924] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[100908.170987] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[100908.173694] wlp1s0: authenticated
[100908.176996] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[100908.177839] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=4)
[100908.179414] wlp1s0: associated
[101087.018403] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101087.023901] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101087.027541] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101087.034094] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101087.035117] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101087.047429] wlp1s0: associated
[101101.955226] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101101.961033] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101101.964820] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101101.967764] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101101.995326] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101101.997458] wlp1s0: associated
[101103.887414] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101103.893505] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101103.896942] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101103.901965] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101103.925155] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101103.927154] wlp1s0: associated
[101107.027041] wlp1s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> lost
[101122.094897] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101122.101080] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101122.103609] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101122.110970] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101122.112600] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101122.114186] wlp1s0: associated
[101124.032222] wlp1s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> lost
[101136.695683] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101136.701410] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101136.703755] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101136.704256] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101136.706096] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101136.707291] wlp1s0: associated
[101142.051920] wlp1s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> lost
[101151.322008] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101151.328345] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101151.332679] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101151.333619] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101151.339988] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101151.341968] wlp1s0: associated
[101158.673690] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101158.679524] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101158.685329] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101158.691771] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101158.820432] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 2/3)
[101158.873374] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 3/3)
[101158.874968] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101158.877117] wlp1s0: associated
[101160.996620] wlp1s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> lost
[101177.412569] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]>
[101177.417908] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101177.420025] wlp1s0: authenticated
[101177.421259] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[101177.423953] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> (capab=0x1001 status=0 aid=2)
[101177.425155] wlp1s0: associated
[101177.425800] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[101179.431047] wlp1s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'CheckVienna free WiFi' [AN2]> lost

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1272389/471632

Reinstalling some packages:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall resolvconf network-manager libnss-resolve
```